# Can't Seem To Find Two-Player Splitscreen for Dynasty Warriors 8 Empires

Tags: xbox-one, dynasty-warriors, dynasty-warriors-8

I recently downloaded Dynasty Warriors 8 Empires (DW8E) from XBox Live.  My roommate and I both created characters under our Live gamer tags.  I log in and start Empire Mode and select my created character.  Start the game and he can't seem to join.  Have tried it on the Pre-Battle screen to no avail.  Tried doing it on Free Mode with multiple officers, still nothing.  Ideas?

Comment: Gimme a moment to boot it up on PC... granted, if the Xbox One version hasn't been updated, there's a chance that you may just be stuck with 2P only when invading/defending in Empire Mode.

Comment: Thanks!  I just downloaded it last night.  I would assume (i know i know i know) that it's the most current version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how 2P works on the DW8E, at least on PC after current update (PC version 1.0.3.0):

In Free Mode Invasions, Defensive Battles, and Raid Scenarios, 2P can join in by pressing start (or F11 on PC, for whatever reason) at the setup screen where you set the difficulty, officers / marching officer, and so forth. Look for the "2P Press Start" prompt at the top of the screen. Event Battles and Quests cannot be done in 2P mode.

In Empire Mode, in any offensive or defensive battle in which you can select officers, 2P can press start to join in for that battle (again, look for the 2P Press Start prompt at the top of the screen). 2P will control the SECOND officer in the list (after the one controlled by 1P). Quests and Event Battles, since they do not permit you to select the officer you are controlling, do not allow for 2P.

Whether all of the above applies to the Xbox One version depends on whether the equivalent updates were pushed out to the Xbox One version. I'm fairly certain the PC version has feature parity with the PS4 version except for online multiplayer.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll check when I get home, and if this is the case, I'll mark you correct!

Comment: Tangentially related to this question: the only created characters that can possibly be available are those on 1P's profile or any "guest characters" appearing in that Empires save game due to how the game handles 2P in general. You may want to recreate your roommate's characters on your save file or vice versa. Also, you can name the individual Created Character groups.

Comment: I just did a double-check against the changelogs for the PC version and compared it to the xbox title update / PS4 patch notes. I would assume the current XBox One version matches PC version 1.0.2.0 (1.0.3.0 was a bugfix for strong attack 3 on the dual hookblades - it could cause a lockup on PC, at least)

Comment: Funny story, I told my roommate the exact same thing last night about recreating his character on my profile.  I doubt he did so.  I did anticipate that part of the error.